# Angles between points in $3$D space where the Origin is not the vertex.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Given two points $P_1,P_2$ in $3$D space that are positioned around a third point $M$, how do you calculate the angle between $P_1,M,P_2$.

I know there are a few questions on here discussing how this can be done about the origin, but I'm confused about how it would change when measuring the angles around some third point that is not $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Compute the angle between $P_1-M,P_2-M$ around the origin.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I'm interested in calculating the angle between the vectors MP1 and MP2. Essentially M, which is not located at 0,0,0 is serving as the vertex about which the angles are measured.

Comment: Move every vector by $-M$, then this will move $M,P_1,P_2$ to $0,P_2-M, P_2-M$ and now the reference point is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach of generalizing stuff is by reducing a new situation to an already understood situation. In your case, you say you know how to compute the angle two points form with the origin, and now want to know the angle two points form with a third point that is not the origin. You can reduce that new situation to the known situation by moving (i.e. translating) the whole setup in such a way that $M$ becomes the origin. Or, if you prefer that view, by moving the coordinate system until its origin lies at $M$, which is essentially the same thing. Translation does not change angles, so this reduction is valid. Translating points means adding some vector. To take $M$ to the origin (i.e. zero vector) you have to add the vector $-M$. So you had $P_1,M,P_2$ and by subtracting $M$ from all of them you now get $P_1-M,0,P_2-M$ which is the situation where the middle point is the origin. Proceed from here in the way you already know.